# DocuSign Redirect URI for obtain individual consent

Tags: php, docusignapi, e-signature

I have a problem. I am building an integration with Docusign's e-signature Api but when trying to generate the uri to obtain user consent the error "redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign" is returning.

My generated redirect_uri is http://192.168.7.205:80/lucascosta/aplication/index.php?KMP=SYS&KMF=assine_online_api&KMA=obterConsentimentoDocuSign

I configured this redirection uri in the docusgin application but it doesn't work. I have already tested the redirection uri and it is working, it seems that Docusgin is unable to redirect to it after obtaining the user's consent.

I tested with the redirect uri http://192.168.7.205:80/lucascosta/aplication/index.php and it worked, however I need it to be the first uri informed

I configured the two redirection Uri's informed in the DocuSign application but only the second informed URI works

I've been reading some articles here on the stackoverflow but I couldn't solve it. Does docusign not accept uri with access parameters?

Sorry for the English, I'm using the google translator because I don't speak or write 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode this URL, I just tested and it works just fine. It would look like this:

```
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.7.205%3A80%2Flucascosta%2Faplication%2Findex.php%3FKMP%3DSYS%26KMF%3Dassine_online_api%26KMA%3DobterConsentimentoDocuSign
```